# Remember login in Sencha 2 app

Tags: sencha-touch-2

We dont want the user to log in each time he/she opens our Sencha 2 app. Its not determined yet if we will serve it through a web browser or package it as a native app with the Sencha build tool.

Any advices how to solve it? Should I use some local storage to remember if user has logged in?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Simple Login project on [github](https://github.com/olegtaranenko/sencha-touch-2-login) to illustrate how I'm using localStorage in credential saving. Feel free to use ideas in your project. Feedback & comment are welcome

Cheers, Oleg

Comment: Cool, thanks, I will check it out and try it end of next week and come with feedback

Comment: Hi Oleg, have implemented your solution now, works like charm. You can see if you want: http://ci.bipper.com/parentapp

Comment: Cool Thomas. I have seen it those time, but currently looks like it is not working... could you share it again?

Answer (score 0):

Here i am going to save the username and password values with the id of 'ext-record-2'.

```
if (values.keepUser) {
    var user = Ext.create('MyApp.model.LoginLocalSave', {
        id: 'ext-record-2',
        uemail: values.uname,
        pword: values.pword,
        isRemember: values.keepUser
    });
    user.save();
}
```

On launching of login screen we need to read the username and password fields from the local storage by using the previously save id 'ext-record-2' and display it on the fields.

```
launch: function() {
    var User = Ext.ModelMgr.getModel('MyApp.model.LoginLocalSave');
    User.load('ext-record-2', {
        success: function(user) {
            Ext.ComponentQuery.query('formpanel #uname')[0].setValue(user.get('uemail'));
            Ext.ComponentQuery.query('formpanel #pword')[0].setValue(user.get('pword'));
            Ext.ComponentQuery.query('formpanel #keepUser')[0].setValue(user.get('isRemember'));
        },
        failure: function() {
            console.warn('Auto-fill login failed.');
        }
    });
},
```

Please visit the below url for full source code by clicking the link. [Solved by solution]

http://saravanakumar.org/blog/2014/04/login-screen-with-username-and-password-remember-in-sencha-touch/